# What kind of information is stored in ModelCheckpoint besides the graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint()` as the only callback while training my model. I have noticed that when "Freezing" the graph it looses a substantial fraction of it`s size. The question is, what else useful is stored in this checkpoint and how can I access it? I am most interested in the history.

I am not using tensorboard for it didn`t quite work out all that well when I tried to implement it into my Colab notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A checkpoint is meant for storing during training whereas a frozen graph is meant for inference.

When you store a checkpoint a graph is **NOT** stored. They store values of variables in a graph as opposed to the whole graph, this is why you cannot resume training without recompiling the model. As it is the ckpt file is not enough.

When a model is stored for inference it not only saves the graph but it also removes any nodes that don't benefit during inference. Some nodes are only required during training and not during inference, like dropout for example. Since ckpts store these training variables along with the rest of the weights, the ckpt may be larger in size. Saved models delete these variables hence are sometimes smaller in size.

This can be confirmed via TensorFlow documentation that quotes:

> Checkpoints capture the exact value of all parameters (tf.Variable objects) used by a model. Checkpoints do not contain any description of the computation defined by the model and thus are typically only useful when source code that will use the saved parameter values is available.
>
> The SavedModel format, on the other hand, includes a serialized description of the computation defined by the model in addition to the parameter values (checkpoint). Models in this format are independent of the source code that created the model. They are thus suitable for deployment via TensorFlow Serving, TensorFlow Lite, TensorFlow.js, or programs in other programming languages (the C, C++, Java, Go, Rust, C# etc. TensorFlow APIs).

For further reading refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/checkpoints